# Mocking does not work as expected go lang

Tags: go, mocking, testify

I am experiencing the following error

```
assert: mock: I don't know what to return because the method call was unexpected.
        Either do Mock.On("Send").Return(...) first, or remove the Send() call.
        This method was unexpected:
                Send(services.ConfirmAccountEmail,repository.User)
```

When consuming real API, it sends the email and mailer.Send is called

So I have an API, which creates Router and routes are registered in Router. Router accepts a parameter of interface `mailer` in its constructor and thats where I want to tweak which mailer would be used - real or the fake.

The code is as following. I know there's a lot of space for improvement, but now I'm primarily interested in mocking

Mailer interface:

```
type Mailer interface {
    Send(email Email, receiver User) error
}
```

Email is also an interface.

The struct that implements Mailer interface:

```
type EmailDelivery struct {
    Config Config
}

func (service EmailDelivery) Send(email Email, receiver User) error {
    //Code
}
```

Router code:

```
type Router struct {
    api         Api
    db          *gorm.DB
    redisClient *redis.Client
    config      Config
    mailer      Mailer
}

func NewRouter(api Api, db *gorm.DB, redisClient *redis.Client, config Config, mailer Mailer) Router {
    return Router{api, db, redisClient, config, mailer}
}

func (router *Router) AddRoutes() {

    router.api.AddRouteWithCors("/register", "POST", WithRequestLog(router.RegisterHandler))
    //...
}


func (router *Router) RegisterHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
            //...

            email := NewConfirmAccountEmail(router.config, "Email subject", "email_template")

            router.mailer.Send(email, user)
}
```

Api code:

```
func (api *Api) InitializeRoutes(mailer Mailer) *Router {
    //...
    router := NewRouter(*api, api.db, api.redisClient, config, mailer)
    router.AddRoutes()

    //...
}
```

Test:

```
type MockMailer struct {
    mock.Mock
}

func (m *MockMailer) Send(email Email, receiver User) error {
    args := m.Called(email, receiver)
    return args.Error(0)
}
```

In test:

```
mailer := new(MockMailer)
mailer.On("Send", mock.Anything, mock.Anything).Return(nil)

//Execute the code that is calling send method - calling endpoint

api := NewApi(config.ServerPort, db, nil)

mailer := new(MockMailer)
router := api.InitializeRoutes(mailer)

req, err := http.NewRequest(http.MethodPost, "/register", bytes.NewReader(body))

w := httptest.NewRecorder()

router.RegisterHandler(w, req)

res := w.Result()

defer res.Body.Close()

mailer.AssertExpectations(t)

//..other expectations
```

Debugging shows that it entered send method, but I still have this error

Could it be that interface is creating an issue?
Or maybe mock.Anything?

Thanks

Comment: One reason I see is you may not be calling any function that calls Send function. And at the end please ensure that you are calling the `mailer.AssertExpectations` function eg `mailer.AssertExpectations(t)`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, I call mailer.AssertExpectations(t), just forgot to post that part. And this is the route test and the endpoint calls the real mailer

Comment: @aldm the expected action from you on Stack Overflow is to actually go ahead and fix the problems in your question, not just confirm that an observation is correct. You're not here to get personal help, you are here to commit a new valuable question to the repository that in the future is going to help others as well.

Comment: Your example wouldn't compile. You're declaring a `mailer` variable twice in the same scope, and the second declaration doesn't set any expectations on the mock.

Answer (score 1):

The method implemented seems to not be the same as the one in the interface; the parameter types differ:
`Send(email Email, receiver User) error` != `Send(services.ConfirmAccountEmail,repository.User)`.

You may want to check if the implemented structure in the tested structure implements your interface with the correct parameter types.

We lack of information to help you resolve this.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I just extended my original question with more information, giving all the relevant code snippets and explanations. And it seems method signature is the same in EmailDelivery structure and in mock itself. Does it help?

Comment: As @Gavin said, your code won't compile. Could you post the full test function ?